# SSL issue and redirects from https to http

Tags: https, apache2, linux

I have a site www.example.com for which i purchased SSL cert and installed.

And it was working fine, I also have a subdomain with app.example.com which was not on SSL.

Both www.example.com and app.example.com are on same IP address.

At later we decided to put SSL only on app.exapmle.com and then i configured SSL with app.example.com and it worked fine,

Now the issue is that Google is indexing my site as https://www.example.com/ and when users hits the web , Invalid security warning is issued and when user allow security issue they are shown my app.example.com contents.

Note: I have my SSL configuration files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

The contents of the ssl.conf are below.

http://pastebin.com/GCWhpQJq

NOTE: I tried solutions in .httaccess but none of those worked. Like redirecting 301 redirects etc

Answer (score 1):

Since app.example.com and www.example.com are on the same IP adress, using https on either of the 2 will use the defined VirtualHost in your ssl.conf, since you did not specify a servername:

> Line 84: #ServerName example.com:443

What you need is VirtualHost on port 443 redirects to http for a given servername

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a wildcard SSL certificate:

```
*.example.com
```

The `*` makes it wildcard and thus you can use it on `www.example.com` and `app.example.com`

Comment: I do not want to purchase a wildcard certificate. I want www.example.com on non HTTPS as this is my static contents.

Comment: please read the answer above by Ronald Swets, that is another option you have.